# HTTP to HTTPS using .fcgi and .htaccess in django

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, fastcgi

I have mysite.fcgi file where the location of django project is written. I have the working .htaccess file.

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I want to make this .htaccess to redirect all the http request to https. I tried to put https:// infront of mysite.fcgi but didn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following lines to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Also see [this page](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/http-https-rewriterule-redirect.html) for a more detailed discussion and other methods.

Comment: Thanks! The link is very useful.